# Inserir td dentro de tr usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

preciso inserir algumas `TD` dentro da `TR` usando **jquery**.

Estou fazendo assim, mas não funciona

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("table tbody .titulo").after("<td class='none'></td><td class='none'></td><td class='none'></td>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="simple-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Página/Recurso</th>
      <th>Ver</th>
      <th>Editar</th>
      <th>Excluir</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="titulo" colspan="4"><b class="blue">Topico 1</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="p1">Contato</td>
      <td><input name="permisao[]" type="checkbox" value="Ver"></td>
      <td><input name="permisao[]" type="checkbox" value="Editar"></td>
      <td><input name="permisao[]" type="checkbox" value="Excluir"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="titulo" colspan="4"><b class="blue">Topico 2</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="p1">Contato</td>
      <td><input name="permisao[]" type="checkbox" value="Ver"></td>
      <td><input name="permisao[]" type="checkbox" value="Editar"></td>
      <td><input name="permisao[]" type="checkbox" value="Excluir"></td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tá funcionando normal. Vc não vê nada porque vc está adicionando TD's vazias.

Comment: Elas precisam estar vazias, só preciso que estejam lá para que a formatação da tabela fique certa.

Comment: Olhe no "inspecionar elementos" do navegador que vc vai ver elas tá.

Comment: Não estão, veja http://prntscr.com/o1hnzf

Comment: Não pode repetir id's. Pelo print, teria que ser `$("#titulo").after(...` onde o id `titulo` seja único na página.

Comment: Descobrir o problema, eu tinha colocado a `$(document).ready(function() {` depois do `jQuery(function($) {`, deveria esta no inicio. Mas ai descobrir outra coisa, o `append` esta adicionando, mas depois que a tabela é carregada, é possível fazer com que seja carregado junto com a tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Confere http://api.jquery.com/append/

Um exemplo genérico:

```js
$("table tr").append("<td>COLUNA_02</td>");
```

```css
table tr td{
background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>COLUNA_01</td>
</tr>
</table>
```